Unexpected behaviour happen when trying to wrap a std::thread instance
I am trying to make a C++ thread pool. First of all, I want to wrap a std::thread instance in a class ThreadObject:
(1) I use a std::thread instance mThread to store a thread.
(2) I use a bool variable mIsFree to control whether this thread is free. I know it might be better to use a std::atomic<bool> variable but I think it would be OK to use the current choice if dealt carefully.
(3) A std::mutex lock instance mThreadObjectMutex is used to protect the thread object.
After that, I define some constructors, assignment operator overloadings and the destructor:
(1) ThreadObject() The constructor without argument only set the mIsFree variable to true. As it is a constructor without argument, I do not use the lock to protect it.
(2) Copy constructor ThreadObject(const ThreadObject &other) and copy assignment operator ThreadObject &operator=(const ThreadObject &other) are deleted. It is natural that the thread object can not be copied.
(3) Move constructor ThreadObject(ThreadObject &&other) noexcept and move assignment operator ThreadObject &operator=(ThreadObject &&other) noexcept are defined similarly. They swap the mThread instance use swap() when both of the threads are free. If not, they will wait for current tasks to stop.
(4) The destructor ~ThreadObject() just join the thread.
I defined 2 functions to execute tasks:
(1) void execute(std::function<void()> func) uses a std::function<void()> input and wrap a new function
std::function<void()> task = [=]() mutable
{
    func();
    this->mIsFree = true;
};

for execution. The mIsFree variable will be set to false before execution and will be set to true when the task is over. If this thread is already occupied, it will wait for the last task to end.
(2) void join() is used to join the thread.
I use gtest provided by Google to test my code. However, I meet some problems with the move constructor ThreadObject(ThreadObject &&other) noexcept, move assignment operator ThreadObject &operator=(ThreadObject &&other) noexcept and the member function void execute(std::function<void()> func):
(0) I define a function to simulate tasks:
void sleepForSeconds(double durationSec)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    while (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count() < durationSec)
    {
        ;
    }
}

(1) As the move constructor ThreadObject(ThreadObject &&other) noexcept and the move assignment operator ThreadObject &operator=(ThreadObject &&other) noexcept have similar behaviours. I only post test case for one of them below:
TEST(ThreadObject_Constructor_move, move)
{
    // Bind test function
    std::function<void()> func = std::bind(sleepForSeconds, 1.0);

    // Initiate thread object and execute one task to occupy the thread. The task will run for 1.0 (s)
    ThreadObject threadObject1 = ThreadObject();
    threadObject1.execute(func);

    // Wait for 0.5 (s) to try the move constructor
    sleepForSeconds(0.5);
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    ThreadObject threadObject2(std::move(threadObject1));
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count();

    // (*** FAIL ***) The move constructor is executed 0.5 (s) later to wait for the task to stop
    EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ(duration, 0.5);

    // Both threads are free after the move constructor is implemented
    EXPECT_TRUE(threadObject1.isThreadFree());
    EXPECT_TRUE(threadObject2.isThreadFree());

    // Join threads
    threadObject1.join();
    threadObject2.join();
}

and I get a failure alarm
Expected equality of these values:
  duration
    Which is: 0
  0.5

(2) I believe the member function void execute(std::function<void()> func) meets a similar problem:
TEST(ThreadObject_Function_execute_func, execute_multiple)
{
    // Bind test function
    double t = 1.0;
    std::function<void()> testFunc = std::bind(sleepForSeconds, t);

    // Initiate thread object and execute one task to occupy the thread. The task will run for 1.0 (s)
    ThreadObject threadObject = ThreadObject();
    threadObject.execute(testFunc);

    // The thread should be occupied.
    EXPECT_FALSE(threadObject.isThreadFree());

    // Wait for 0.5 (s), the thread should still be busy.
    sleepForSeconds(0.5);

    // The task will not be executed until the current task is done.
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    threadObject.execute(testFunc);
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count();

    // (** FAIL **) It takes 0.5 (s) for the rest of the last task.
    EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ(duration, 0.5);

    // Wait for 0.5 (s), the thread should still be busy.
    sleepForSeconds(0.5);

    // (** FAIL **)
    EXPECT_FALSE(threadObject.isThreadFree());

    // Wait for 0.5 (s), and the task is done.
    sleepForSeconds(0.5);
    EXPECT_TRUE(threadObject.isThreadFree());

    // Join thread
    threadObject.join();
}

and the failure alarm writes
Expected equality of these values:
  duration
    Which is: 0
  0.5

Value of: threadObject.isThreadFree()
  Actual: true
Expected: false

My full code is as follows:
    class ThreadObject
    {
    private:
        /// @brief Thread
        std::thread mThread;

        /// @brief Is the thread free
        bool mIsFree;

        /// @brief The mutex lock for the thread object
        std::mutex mThreadObjectMutex;

    public:
        /// @brief The constructor without argument.
        ThreadObject()
        {
            mIsFree = true;
        }

        /// @brief The copy constructor is deleted
        ThreadObject(const ThreadObject &other) = delete;
        
        /// @brief The copy assignment operator is deleted.
        ThreadObject &operator=(const ThreadObject &other) = delete;

        /// @brief The move constructor.
        ThreadObject(ThreadObject &&other) noexcept
        {
            if (this != &other)
            {
                std::lock(mThreadObjectMutex, other.mThreadObjectMutex);
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockSelf(mThreadObjectMutex, std::adopt_lock);
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockOther(other.mThreadObjectMutex, std::adopt_lock);

                // Wait for the two threads to stop

                if (mThread.joinable())
                {
                    mThread.join();
                }

                if (other.mThread.joinable())
                {
                    other.mThread.join();
                }

                // swap threads

                mThread.swap(other.mThread);
                mIsFree = other.mIsFree;
                other.mIsFree = true;
            }
        }

        /// @brief The move assignment operator
        ThreadObject &operator=(ThreadObject &&other) noexcept
        {
            if (this != &other)
            {
                std::lock(mThreadObjectMutex, other.mThreadObjectMutex);
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockSelf(mThreadObjectMutex, std::adopt_lock);
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockOther(other.mThreadObjectMutex, std::adopt_lock);

                // Wait for the two threads to stop

                if (mThread.joinable())
                {
                    mThread.join();
                }

                if (other.mThread.joinable())
                {
                    other.mThread.join();
                }

                // swap threads

                mThread.swap(other.mThread);
                mIsFree = true;
                other.mIsFree = true;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        /// @brief The destructor
        ~ThreadObject()
        {
            // Lock the thread object mutex lock to avoid multi-thread competition
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mThreadObjectMutex);

            if (mThread.joinable())
            {
                mThread.join();
            }
        }

        /// @brief To get the thread's status whether this thread is free.
        bool isThreadFree() const
        {
            return mIsFree;
        }

        /// @brief To execute a input void function
        void execute(std::function<void()> func)
        {
            // Lock the thread object mutex lock to avoid multi-thread competition
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mThreadObjectMutex);

            // Wait for the last task to stop
            if (mThread.joinable())
            {
                mThread.join();
            }

            // Occupy the current thread
            mIsFree = false;

            // Configure the function to execute
            std::function<void()> task = [=]() mutable
            {
                func();
                this->mIsFree = true;
            };

            // Execute task
            mThread = std::thread(task);
        }

        /// @brief To join the thread.
        void join()
        {
            // Lock the thread object mutex lock to avoid multi-thread competition
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mThreadObjectMutex);

            if (mThread.joinable())
            {
                mThread.join();
                mIsFree = true;
            }
        }
    };

I tried some other tests, when I don't use sleepForSeconds(0.5) to wait for 0.5 seconds to simulate some kind of act from another thread, my code works just fine.
Is there anything wrong with my code? Or anything wrong with my tests?

Testing for an exact duration when your program runs at the whim of an operating system scheduler is doomed to failure.

std::chrono::seconds::count() returns an integer. It can't possibly be euqal to 0.5

Even your "full code" only declares a class, it can't be compiled to an executable that demonstrates the behaviour. Please provide a [mcve].

@RetiredNinja What you suggested is true. I changed my "simulation" process and the result turns out OK. Thank you for your attention.

@IgorTandetnik That's the point! Thank you!

@UlrichEckhardt I'm sorry for not providing a  minimal reproducible example. I am using a google test framework and I forgot to rewrite to a reproducible example. However, it turned out the problem has nothing to do with multi-threading as is suggested by IgorTandetnik and the problem is solved. Thank you for your advice.

Happy you fixed the bug! Still, just a note: The [mcve] is required exactly because it forces you to first reduce the problem. I believe that you would have found yourself that multithreading has nothing to do with it.

On the one hand, as is reminded by @Igor Tandetnik, the function std::chrono::seconds::count() return s an integer and it can't possibly be equal to 0.5. As a result, the sleepForSeconds() in the test should by changed to:
void sleepForSeconds(double durationSec)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    while (getDurationSeconds(start, std::chrono::steady_clock::now()) < durationSec)
    {
        ;
    }
}

and a supplement function is used to get a duration counted in seconds:
double getDurationSeconds(std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start, std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end)
{
    std::chrono::duration duration = end - start;
    double durationSeconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(duration).count() / 1e6;
    return durationSeconds;
}

On the other hand, as is warned by @Retired Ninja: "Testing for an exact duration when your program runs at the whim of an operating system scheduler is doomed to failure", we should know that the test is just a rough simulation of real operations. As a result, we should not use EXPECT_EQ in our test but EXPECT_NEAR instead. The tests are changed to:
TEST(ThreadObject_Constructor_move, move)
{
    // Bind test function
    std::function<void()> func = std::bind(sleepForSeconds, 1.0);

    // Initiate thread object and execute one task to occupy the thread. The task will run for 1.0 (s)
    ThreadObject threadObject1 = ThreadObject();
    threadObject1.execute(func);

    // Wait for 0.5 (s) to try the move constructor
    sleepForSeconds(0.5);
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    ThreadObject threadObject2(std::move(threadObject1));
    double durationSeconds = getDurationSeconds(start, std::chrono::steady_clock::now());

    // The move constructor is executed 0.5 (s) later to wait for the task to stop
    EXPECT_NEAR(0.5, durationSeconds, 1e-3);

    // Both threads are free after the move constructor is implemented
    EXPECT_TRUE(threadObject1.isThreadFree());
    EXPECT_TRUE(threadObject2.isThreadFree());

    // Join threads
    threadObject1.join();
    threadObject2.join();
}

and
TEST(ThreadObject_Function_execute_func, execute_multiple)
{
    // Bind test function
    double t = 1.0;
    std::function<void()> testFunc = std::bind(sleepForSeconds, t);

    // Initiate thread object and execute one task to occupy the thread. The task will run for 1.0 (s)
    ThreadObject threadObject = ThreadObject();
    threadObject.execute(testFunc);

    // The thread should be occupied.
    EXPECT_FALSE(threadObject.isThreadFree());

    // Wait for 0.5 (s), the thread should still be busy.
    sleepForSeconds(0.5);

    // The task will not be executed until the current task is done.
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    threadObject.execute(testFunc);
    double durationSeconds = getDurationSeconds(start, std::chrono::steady_clock::now());

    // It takes 0.5 (s) for the rest of the last task.
    EXPECT_NEAR(0.5, durationSeconds, 1e-3);

    // Wait for 0.5 (s), the thread should still be busy.
    sleepForSeconds(0.5);
    EXPECT_FALSE(threadObject.isThreadFree());

    // Wait for 0.501 (s), the task is done. The more 0.001 (s) is needed for not precise time and computational expense.
    sleepForSeconds(0.501);
    EXPECT_TRUE(threadObject.isThreadFree());

    // Join
    threadObject.join();
}

I want to thank @Igor Tandetnik and @Retired Ninja for their attention on this problem. I really appreciate that.

Why divide microseconds by 1e6 rather than just using std::chrono::duration<double> which will do the conversion for you?

@AlanBirtles Thank you for your advice. I am not very familiar with the std::chrono library. What you suggest is way more better.
